# Why can I sometimes modify a const object and sometimes not?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I have two pieces of code where I'm trying to modify a value at read-only location. One of them is throwing an error.

1stcode.c

```
void main()
{
  int const k=9;
  int *p=&k;
  *p=10;
  printf("%d",k);
}
```

2ndcode.c

```
void main()
{
      int  const * p=5;
      printf("%d",++(*p));
}
```

Here `1stcode.c` allows me to simply modify the read only memory location but `2ndcode.c` throws an error:

> `error: increment of read-only location '*p'`

Why is it so when both locations are read only?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I understand people that do. In your first code you cast an address of a `const` qualified variable to one that pretends that it is not. Then you ask us why the compiler accepts this?

Answer (score 4):

The 1st example will also not compile if you turn your compiler warning level up.

---

*Note also that in the 2nd example, you're declaring a pointer to address 5, which is not going to ever do anything useful.*

Comment: What does the standard say about this ? Is conversion allowed or is it implementation defined behavior or is it something else ?

Comment: @Parminder: I'm not sure; it's not described in section 6.3 (effectively the list of implicit conversions), so I guess that makes it undefined.  Either way, it's a bad idea to actually do it!

Answer (score 2):

The first code is incorrect too.

You point with a pointer to `int` to an object defined as `const int` and modify this. This is an ill-formed C program, but the compiler doesn't detect the error (well, it probably give you a warning). You can expect bugs to show up because of this, especially if you turn optimizations on (the compiler can assume that the value hasn't changed).

The code still compiles because C is weakly typed and allows implicit conversion between incompatible types (in this case, from `const int*` to `int*`.

(Note that this is different in C++, which is more strict and would give you a compilation error if you tried such conversion.)

Comment: "This is an ill-formed C program" - unless I have my definitions mixed up, it's *not* ill-formed in C. It just has undefined behavior, and it would be ill-formed in C++.

Answer (score 0):

From the [online C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.7.3 Type Qualifiers**
> ...
> 5 If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
> of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is
> made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
> with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.<sup>115)</sup>

You're attempting to modify the contents of `k` (an object defined with a const-qualified type) through `*p` (an lvalue with a non-const-qualified type), thus the behavior is undefined, where "undefined" simply means the standard places no requirement on the compiler to do anything in particular.  In this case, the compiler translated the code in such a way that the operation "works", but you shouldn't rely on that behavior being repeatable.  A smarter compiler (or a more stringent warning setting) might issue a diagnostic and cease translation at that point.  Or it might not.  This problem's a bugger to detect in the general case, which is why I suspect the behavior is simply left undefined.

In the second case, you've declared `p` as a pointer to a `const int`; you're not allowed to modify `*p`, which `++(*p)` attempts to do.